# Checking status of a process runned

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've an application that run a subprocess and i would like to determine if the subprocess is completely loaded.
My goal is to run another app, wait for it to load, and close the "calling app".
I thought that maybe the best solution would be to use the library `psutil` but i can only check if status is running or not. Any idea?

EDIT :

running on win x64

```
cmd = 'path_to.exe'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

isOpen = False
while (isOpen == False) :
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name().lower() in ['path_to.exe'] and proc.status() == psutil.STATUS_RUNNING :
                isOpen = True
        except :
            pass
```

psutil status are there : https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#process-status-constants

Comment: Please show the code you used to launch the subprocess.  What determines whether or not the subprocess has "fully loaded"?

Comment: @0x5453 i've added the code.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to ask. Is there a reason you don't simply check the status of `subprocess.Popen()` after, say, 1 second?

Comment: @tripleee the return of the subprocess it's always "emtpy" (no return ?)